# React-Native connect Socket IO to aws elb securely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So, I am trying to connect react native and socket io to my aws elb server.

I can connect with socket io locally, but cannot do so remotely to the aws server.

I always get this message in my console `SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert`. From my understanding, this message occurs whenever the sockets are trying to connect, but fails. Since I set the `reconnectionAttempts` to 3, I see this message 3 times.

Here is my code:

```
// front end
  this.socket = io.connect(
  port, // https://api...
  {
    reconnection: true,
    reconnectionDelay: 500,
    secure: true,
    reconnectionAttempts: 3,
    transports: ["websocket"],
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    jsonp: false
  }
);


// back end
  var port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
  const server = app.listen(port); // connects to express server

  const connectionOptions = {
    jsonp: false,
    secure: true,
    transports: ['websocket']
  }; 

  const io = socket(server, connectionOptions);
```

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked like the issue was with setting up socket usage with aws elb: https://anandhub.wordpress.com/2016/10/06/websocket-ebs/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

I ended up replacing socket io with firebase for the real time chat.

Comment: This isn't really a solution. It's just doing something else instead.